# how to access api 19 for android in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am currently using Eclipse SDK for Android development and I am targeting API 19 but I'm not able to update as I'm not getting anything with description uninstalled in my SDK manager.

Can someone please help? I need to know how I can update the SDK and access API 19 in my Eclipse ADT?

Comment: Have you updated the APIs using SDK Manager?

Comment: Use Android SDK Manager to update sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the SDK Manager, which can be found at the 5th button from the left of your toolbar (assuming default eclipse view)

Alternatively you can click on 'window' and then 'SDK Manager'. This should then load the SDK manager up and allow you to download API 19.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "description uninstalled", open window > android SDK manager and download everything under Android 4.4 - API 19 and update everything that wants to be updated

Answer (score 0):

first of all go to SDK Manager ,and update what ever that are not installed ,press on the button and install.After that go to Eclipse ,Help-->check for updates.....

Answer (score 0):

First you have to go adt bundle folder and then open sdk.exe in administration mode and then install the api .