# Can't see/select API 19 in Eclipse Indigo in project properties

Tags: android, eclipse

Trying to update an app to newer version of android.  Downloaded/installed API 19 and supporting files via SDK manager (as administrator), SDK manager shows that all files are installed - but when selecting [project properties - android]... api 19 is not listed. Can't include screenshots since i don't have enough reputation points - but screenshot would show SDK manager with installed android 4.4.2 (api 19), and a second screenshot showing android properties only listing up to api 18.

Closest post/solution found was  [how to access api 19 for android in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904641/how-to-access-api-19-for-android-in-eclipse) 
but didn't help...
using Eclipse indigo

Many thanks for your help!!

Comment: Did you restart eclipse?

Comment: yes restarted eclipse and computer - a few times

Comment: Ok, then you have to look for Updates as Ogre_BGR says.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update eclipse too after updating the SDK. Go to Help -> Check for updates and see if some component needs update.

Comment: i checked for updates numerous times - was going to upgrade to kepler, but figured that was overkill...